# What is wrong with my hook_schema code?

Tags: 7, database

I am pulling my hair for the past half of the day trying to figure out what is wrong. Here is my `hook_schema` function:

```
<?php

function image_gallery_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['gallery'] = array(
    'description' => 'The main store for gallery entity',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key for our table of gallery',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'User id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'Title of the gallery',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' =>TRUE,
       ),
      'created' => array(
        'description' => 'Creation time',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 0,
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'changed' => array(
        'description' => 'Changed time',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 0,
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'gall_description' => array(
        'description' => 'Description of gallery',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' =>TRUE,
       ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );

  $schema['photos'] = array(
    'description' => 'For storing photos',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key for photo',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'g_id' => array(
        'description' => 'Gallery id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'full_path' => array(
        'description' => 'full photo path',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'short_path' => array(
        'description' => 'short photo path',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'img_description' => array(
        'description' => 'Image description',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
    'indexes' => array(
      'g_id' => array('g_id'),
    ),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'gid' => array(
        'table' => 'gallery',
        'columns' => array('g_id' => 'id'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

I checked all the brackets and everything seems to be in place. It does create `gallery` table, but fails to create `photo` table. Error I get:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I was trying to see how `gallery` schema is different from `photos` but I can't find anything. Maybe something is wrong with `indexes` and `foreign keys`? I checked multiple examples and everything seems to be the same. If someone could help me out, I would be more thank thankful.

Comment: Did you check that there doesn't exist a photos table. Just to be sure, and to comply with Drupal code standards, your tables should be named _image_gallery_gallery_ and _image_gallery_photos_

Comment: Do you get an error when you enable the module?

Comment: Yes, please prefix your tables appropriately. Uninstall, and make sure the tables do not exist in the database - reenable the module, and see if the error persists.

Comment: @juankvillegas I will update my table names accordingly, and yes, I get when I try to update my module. 

 I already did that, every time I try to enable my module and create those tables, I drop previously created one. So the problem persists sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be because you are adding the `unsigned` attribute to `text` fields.

Comment: @Viktor, if this is not the reason, please copy and paste the error you are getting to have a clue about what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the indexes array in photos array. It should look something like

```
function image_gallery_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  $schema['gallery'] = array(
    'description' => 'The main store for gallery entity',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key for our table of gallery',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'User id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'Title of the gallery',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' =>TRUE,
       ),
      'created' => array(
        'description' => 'Creation time',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 0,
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'changed' => array(
        'description' => 'Changed time',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 0,
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'gall_description' => array(
        'description' => 'Description of gallery',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' =>TRUE,
       ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );

  $schema['photos'] = array(
    'description' => 'For storing photos',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key for photo',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'g_id' => array(
        'description' => 'Gallery id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'full_path' => array(
        'description' => 'full photo path',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'short_path' => array(
        'description' => 'short photo path',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'img_description' => array(
        'description' => 'Image description',
        'type' => 'text',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'gid' => array(
        'table' => 'gallery',
        'columns' => array('g_id' => 'id'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Lemme know if you have any confusions.